# How check array by index

Tags: jquery

I want to write a simple example, which will count messages. **Very important: I need to check if the array is null or not using index**, like this (main_arr[0]):

```
<body>

<input type="button" id="btn1" name="click" value="click"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var main_arr ;

$("#btn1").click(function () {
 if (main_arr[0] == null) {
    main_arr = [];
    alert("Array was initialized!");

} else {
    main_arr.push("message");
    alert("In array " + main_arr.length + " messages!");
}

});


});
</script>

</body>
```

How to check if main_arr[0] have value?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't initialize the variable when you define it? `var main_arr = [];`. Then you wouldn't have to check at all in your click handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

Is 'main_arr' defined?

```
if (typeof main_arr != "undefined")
{
}
```

Does 'main_arr' has any elements?

```
if (main_arr.length > 0)
{
}
```

So your code becomes

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var main_arr;

    $("#btn1").click(function ()
    {
        if (typeof main_arr == 'undefined')
        {
            main_arr = [];
        }

        if (main_arr.length > 0)
        {
            // It has elements. Time to check for the '0th' element
        }
        else
        {
            // No elements. Push one.
            main_arr.push('message');
        }

    });
});
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (typeof main_arr == 'undefined') {
  init
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
if (main_arr.length == 0) {
```

Comment: Very important! I need check by index! It's my task requirements!

Comment: if main_arr is undefined this will still crash

Comment: Long to explain. I have a multidimensional array, and I can only check through indexes